# How to change SQL Server 2005 from Windows Authentication to SQL Authentication?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have installed SQL Server 2005 in Windows Authentication, now I want to change it to SQL Authentication.
However, I cannot reinstall SQL SERVER and Management again, because it will lose the data in it.
Also I want to know what changes do I need to make in my Connection class to open connection, as my current is

```
public SqlConnection con= new sqlConnection("server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=Restaurant;integrated security=sspi");
```

Just need to ask one more thing, I can see my database in WIndows Auth and in SQL auth, so how can i change, so that any other user need to login before it peeps into my database. thanks

Comment: First Google search result for "How to change SQL Server 2005 from Windows Authentication to SQL Authentication": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use SQL Server authentication, change the line:

```
public SqlConnection con= new sqlConnection("server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=Restaurant;integrated security=sspi");
```

to

```
public SqlConnection con= new sqlConnection("server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=Restaurant;user id=#USERID#;password=#PASSWORD#;Trusted_Connection=False");
```

Where "#USERID#" and #PASSWORD# are the specific User ID and Password respectively

Comment: just need to ask one more thing, I can see my database in WIndows Auth and in SQL auth, so how can i change, so that any other user need to login before it peeps into my database. thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Using SQL Server Management Studio**
**To change security authentication mode**

In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the server, and then click Properties.

On the Security page, under Server authentication, select the new server authentication mode, and then click OK.

In the SQL Server Management Studio dialog box, click OK to acknowledge the requirement to restart SQL Server.

In Object Explorer, right-click your server, and then click Restart. If SQL Server Agent is running, it must also be restarted.

**To enable the sa login**

In Object Explorer, expand Security, expand Logins, right-click sa, and then click Properties.

On the General page, you might have to create and confirm a password for the login.

On the Status page, in the Login section, click Enabled, and then click OK.

**Using Transact-SQL
To enable the sa login**

In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of Database Engine.

On the Standard bar, click New Query.

Copy and paste the following example into the query window and click Execute. The following example enables the sa login and sets a new password.

```
ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE ;
GO
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>' ;
GO
```

You   can pass below sample(change appropriate UID & PWD) connection string in your connection object

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Manish, its very helpful.
just need to ask one more thing, I can see my database in WIndows Auth and in SQL auth, so how can i change, so that any other user need to login before it peeps into my database.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

To change the server security type:
You just need open SQL Server Management Object Explorer, right click the server, go in Properties, Security page, under server authentication, select the mode you want.

To modify the connection string: 
1. You need to have a SQL user first. Still in the SQL Server Management Object Explorer, right click on user which under Security node, click new, then you can create one.
2. add the "User ID" and "Password" segment to the connection string.